# codeigniter pagination result change

Tags: codeigniter

When I am on the first page of my codeigniter pagination my result should display **Showing 1 to 1 of 3 (3 Pages)** currently the first page is starts at 0 **Showing 0 to 0 of 3 (3 Pages)**

The page number is the uri segment(3). How can I fix my code so that the fist page is 1 **Showing 1 to 1 of 3 (3 Pages)**

```
$page_number = $this->uri->segment(3);

if (isset($page_number)) {
    $page = $page_number;
} else {
    $page = 1;
}

$paginations_lang = "Showing %d to %d of %d (%d Pages)";

$data['results'] = sprintf($paginations_lang, ($user_group_total) ? (($page - 1) * $admin_limit) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * $admin_limit) > ($user_group_total - $admin_limit)) ? $user_group_total : ((($page - 1) * $admin_limit) + $admin_limit), $user_group_total, ceil($user_group_total / $admin_limit));
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index($offset = 0) {

$this->load->model('admin/user/model_user_group');

$this->load->library('pagination');

$data['title'] = "Users Group";

$success = $this->session->userdata('success');

if (isset($success)) {
    $data['success'] = $this->session->userdata('success');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('success');
} else {
    $data['success'] = '';
}

$page_number = $this->uri->segment(3);

if (isset($page_number)) {
    $page = $page_number;
} else {
    $page = 1;
}

$admin_limit = 1;

$user_group_total = $this->model_user_group->getTotalUserGroups();

$results = $this->model_user_group->getUserGroups($admin_limit, $this->uri->segment(3));

$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'admin/users_group';
$config['total_rows'] = $user_group_total;
$config['per_page'] = $admin_limit;
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;

$config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
$config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
$config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
$config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
$config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
$config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
$config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";

$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

foreach ($results as $result) {
$data['user_groups'][] = array(
'user_group_id' => $result['user_group_id'],
'name' => $result['name'],
'edit' => site_url('admin/users_group/edit' .'/'. $result['user_group_id'])
);
}

$paginations_lang = "Showing %d to %d of %d (%d Pages)";

$data['results'] = sprintf($paginations_lang, ($user_group_total) ? (($page - 1) * $admin_limit) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * $admin_limit) > ($user_group_total - $admin_limit)) ? $user_group_total : ((($page - 1) * $admin_limit) + $admin_limit), $user_group_total, ceil($user_group_total / $admin_limit));

$this->load->view('template/user/users_group_list.tpl', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the result out put.

It need to be changed around so page 1 would be come page 0

Old

```
if (isset($page_number)) {
$page = $page_number;
} else {
$page = 1;
}
```

New

```
if (isset($page_number)) {
$page = $page_number;
} else {
$page = 0;
}
```

**Result**

Old

```
$paginations_lang = "Showing %d to %d of %d (%d Pages)";

$data['results'] = sprintf($paginations_lang, ($user_group_total) ? (($page - 1) * $admin_limit) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * $admin_limit) > ($user_group_total - $admin_limit)) ? $user_group_total : ((($page - 1) * $admin_limit) + $admin_limit), $user_group_total, ceil($user_group_total / $admin_limit));
```

New

```
$paginations_lang = "Showing %d to %d of %d (%d Pages)";

$data['results'] = sprintf($paginations_lang, ($user_group_total) ? (($page - 0) * $admin_limit) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 0) * $admin_limit) > ($user_group_total - $admin_limit)) ? $user_group_total : ((($page - 0) * $admin_limit) + $admin_limit), $user_group_total, ceil($user_group_total / $admin_limit));
```